# Creating a list in python using os.popen

Tags: python, popen

Previously, I have been able to create lists using a command similar to the following:

`os.popen('ls *.fits > samplelist')`

Now I'm attempting to organize the files into lists by grouping them by number.

The files are named as following:

**Name_0000_J.fits, Name_0001_J.fits, Name_0002_J.fits, ect.**

I've attempted to run this line of code but it just creates the list **skylist_J_1** and leaves it empty.

`os.popen('for num in {0000..0089} ; do ls Name_$num\_J.fits >> skylist_J_1 ; done')`

I ran the above in a command line and it works perfectly. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have come up with this solution but it is rather bulky. Hopefully there is a cleaner way to accomplish this.

```
def MkSkylist(qmin,qmax,name,band,quadrant):

    a = qmax-qmin+1

    ran = np.arange(qmin,qmax+1)
    num = [0]*a

    i = 0
    while i < a:
        num[i] = np.array2string(ran[i]).zfill(4)
        i = i + 1    

    os.popen('ls '+name+num[0]+'_'+band+'.fits > skylist_'+band+'_'+quadrant)

    i = 1
    while i < a:
        os.popen('ls '+name+num[0]+'_'+band+'.fits >> skylist_'+band+'_'+quadrant)
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: why don't you write it in Python without `os.popen`.  OR put it in file and run `os.popen("filename")`

Comment: Your question isn't really a Python question, but more of a `bash` question, since you're not solving the problem in Python. However, possibly the issue is caused by the backslash in your statement. You should really look into `pathlib` though, for example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob - the main reason would be to write something that doesn't rely on a specific shell running  your script and having a script that works across OSes.

Comment: I think it's indeed a Python question: in the shell we can write `for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done` (which prints 3 lines: `2`, `3` and `4`). But using `os.popen` or `subprocess.Popen` this prints one line: `{2..4}`. So the question is about how to achieve writing a bash-for loop in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the syntax of the for loop: even though that syntax is valid in bash, it seems Python doesn't like it. Not even with `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)`.

So, try using [seq](http://manpages.org/seq) instead:

```py
os.popen("for num in $(seq 0 89); do printf "Name_%04dJ.fits\n" $num >> skylist_J_1; done");
```

Which generates a file `skylist_J_1` with this content:

```
Name_0001J.fits
Name_0002J.fits
Name_0003J.fits
Name_0004J.fits
...
Name_0086J.fits
Name_0087J.fits
Name_0088J.fits
Name_0089J.fits
```

Also notice you can put the file redirection outside, which is more similar to your first example (using `>` instead of `>>`):

```py
os.popen('for num in $(seq 0 89); do printf "Name_%04dJ.fits\n" $num; done > skylist_J_1')
```

Comment: Here you can see the explanation of why the other syntax doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622318/correct-way-in-python-to-write-a-bash-for-loop-with-subprocess In short, `os.popen` uses `/bin/sh`, which in your system is a shell that doesn't support that syntax `{X..Y}`