# Correct way in Python to write a bash for loop with `subprocess`

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

In [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621752/creating-a-list-in-python-using-os-popen) I saw that this syntax of `bash` when writing a `for` loop doesn't seem to work in Python:

```sh
~ $ for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done
2
3
4
```

As instead of 4 different iterations, it does a single one:

```py
>>> print(subprocess.check_output("for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done", shell=True).decode())
{2..4}
```

Why is it this syntax is not supported in Python?

I see this other syntax is indeed supported:

```py
>>> print(subprocess.check_output("for num in 2 3 4; do echo $num; done", shell=True).decode())
2
3
4
```

Comment: `check_output("bash -c 'for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done' ", shell=True).decode()`

Comment: So the issue is Python is not using Bash but Dash?

Comment: This shows that it probably uses old `sh` instead of `bash` https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/

Comment: What's your `SHELL` environment variable setting to? If it's not `bash`, does changing it to that help?

Comment: this works for me `check_output(...., executable='/bin/bash')`

Comment: @furas Thanks. From that link I see `/bin/sh` is the one Python uses, not the current user's shell. So adding `executable=/bin/bash` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post [How to use the bash shell with Python's subprocess module instead of /bin/sh](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/04/how-use-bash-shell-python-subprocess-instead-binsh/) shows that it uses `/bin/sh` but you can use `executable='/bin/bash'` to change it

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output("for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash').decode())
```

---

Eventually you can use `bash -c "command"`

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output('bash -c "for num in {2..4}; do echo $num; done" ', shell=True).decode())
```